# Kuzzle getUser by JWT Token generated early

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kuzzle

I have Integrated [kuzzle](https://kuzzle.io/index.html) in ReactJS app using **Kuzzle-SDK**

Everything works Fine first. I Login using `kuzzle.auth.login('local', credentials)`
and save the **JWT Token** in `localStorage` and `kuzzle.auth.getCurrentUser()` return

```
{
  "profileIds": [
    "admin"
  ],
  "_kuzzle_info": {
    "author": "usamaashraf82",
    "createdAt": 1573960408796,
    "updatedAt": null,
    "updater": null
  }
}
```

After refreshing the Browser

I try to `kuzzle.auth.checkToken();`and it returns `{valid: true, expiresAt: 1540824822897 }`
and i try to `kuzzle.auth.getCurrentUser()` but then its return

```
{
  "profileIds": [
    "anonymous"
  ],
  "name": "Anonymous"
}
```

I want to Ask what I am doing Wrong or How I can solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [kuzzle.auth.checkToken](https://docs.kuzzle.io/sdk/js/6/controllers/auth/check-token/) method is only meant to check a token validity.

If you want to use a previously acquired token, you can set the `kuzzle.jwt` property with the corresponding token. (See [Kuzzle properties documentation](https://docs.kuzzle.io/sdk/js/6/core-classes/kuzzle/properties/)).

```
const token = await kuzzle.auth.login('local', credentials);
// [...]
kuzzle.jwt = token;
await kuzzle.auth.getCurrentUser(); // now loggued with the user corresponding to the token
```

Please consider that storing authentication token in the browser localstorage is [usually a bad idea](https://www.rdegges.com/2018/please-stop-using-local-storage/) because almost every script included in you webpage will be able to read them and connect without your user knowledge.

Comment: Surely you meant "checkToken is only meant to check a token's validity"? :-)